# NULL Predicate in Windows SharePoint Services Search SQL Syntax

Tags: sharepoint, search

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472953.aspx is stated that queries like

```
WHERE column IS NULL
```

and

```
WHERE column IS NOT NULL
```

are allowed. *IS NOT NULL* is working. *IS NULL* does not return any items. I think this is because the SharePoint indexer does not include null values in the Index. But this syntax is documented at MSDN.

Does anybody know how to use the IS NULL predicate correctly?

Comment: Do you mean IS NULL on the last line of your question?

Comment: Yes I do. Edited. Thanks Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for a resolution to the same issue but unfortunately could not find any.

I'm planning to run 2 search queries, one a normal query (Set A) and other a "IS NOT NULL" query (Set B) and return A minus B as result set. Let me know if you have a better idea

Comment: I think this would do the job, but it's not suitable for what I want to do. (The query is user generated. I'd rather don't allow IS NULL expressions)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, see this [blog post](http://vspug.com/smc750/2007/06/20/custom-cross-list-search-development-pitfalls-part-two/) for more info.